# Can I search a JSON column for multiple values without OR?

Tags: mariadb

I'm hoping to perform a query like this:

`SELECT * from table1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(field1,[1,3,5]);`

Rows look like:

```
id | field1
-------------------
1    [1,5,8,6,4]
2    [2]
3    [1,3]
4    [6,8,12]
```

I don't want to search explicitly for `[1,3,5]`, instead I want to return rows where `field1` contains `1` and/or `3` and/or `5`.

Is this possible in a single statement, or would I need to have repeated `JSON_CONTAINS()` statements with `OR`?

I believe in Postgres you would do:

`SELECT * from table1 WHERE field1 && '[1,3,5]'`

Thank you

Comment: You need the JSON_OVERLAPS function, available since MySQL 18.0.17 (see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c9fa362484049c46aba0084fdd4afc2)) and will be available in MariaDB since 10.9 (see [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_overlaps/#:~:text=starting%20with%2010.9-,JSON_OVERLAPS,-MariaDB%20starting%20with&text=JSON_OVERLAPS%20is%20added%20in%20MariaDB%20starting%20from%2010.9.,-Syntax)). What version of MariaDB are you currently using?.

Comment: Dang, I'm on 10.7.3, I guess i'll have to resort to JSON_CONTAINS() for the time being. Thank you for the tip

Comment: An option using [JSON_TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=5df5b5251ba784f0d13168b893487bb0).